# Is "to board Flight 139" an attribute or complement in this sentence?

Tags: adjectives, parsing

I am trying to diagram this sentence:

> This is the last call for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57.

Here is my specific problem: I'm not sure "to board Flight 139" here is either attribute or complement (esp. "for passengers", I do not know the role it plays in this sentence in structure "for somebody to do something").

Can anyone explain how this might work grammatically?

Comment: I think "for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57" is an appositive for "this"

Answer (score 1):

Notice that all three sentences:

> This is the last call for passengers.
>   This is the last call to board Flight 139.
>   This is the last call at Gate 57.

Are all correct and the final phrases all mean much the same as in the the full sentence.  This suggests that each phrase is independent of the others, and in particular "to board flight 139" is not an adjunct of "passengers".

Comment: thank you. so the "to board Flight 139" is complement.

Answer (score 0):

to board Flight 139 =

an infinitive phrase

> What Is an Infinitive Phrase? (with Examples) ***An infinitive phrase is
>   the infinitive form of a verb plus any complements and modifiers.***
>
> The complement of an infinitive verb will often be its direct object,
>   and the modifier will often be an adverb.

For example: He likes to

> knead the dough slowly. (The infinitive verb is to knead. The
>   complement is its direct object (the dough). The modifier is the
>   adverb (slowly). They all make up the infinitive phrase (the shaded
>   text).)
>
> Examples of Infinitive Phrases Here are some examples of
>   infinitive phrases (shaded):
>   He helped **to build the roof**.
>   The officer returned **to help the inspectors.**
>   Let me show you the best way **to fit a
>   door** quickly.
>   She tells you **to dance** like no one is watching.

[infinitive phrases](https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/infinitive_phrase.htm)

This=subject

is the last call= predicate

for passengers= prepositional phrase

to board Flight 139  = infinitive clause

In simple grammatical terms.

a call in airline terminology means an announcement over a loudspeaker.

Just like:

**This is the last chance for him to do his homework.**

There are thousands of prepositional phrases with for + a noun or pronoun.

Grammatical function of infinitive clauses:

> "A subordinate clause with an infinitive often acts as the subject or
>   object of the main clause. In the following examples, the whole
>   infinitive clause [in bold] is understood as the subject of is human,
>   is decadent or was unnecessary.
>
> - To err is human.
> - To drink Martinis before noon is decadent.
> - For Mervyn to redirect Maggie's mail was unnecessary."

[...]

> "And in the following examples, the whole infinitive clause [again in
>   bold] is understood as the direct object of hates, loves and expected.
>
> - Jim hates to wash his car."

[grammatical function](https://www.thoughtco.com/infinitive-clause-grammar-1691062)

Comment: of cause for passengers is prepositional phrase, I want to know, however, is the role this prepositional phrase play in this sentence, and obviously prepositional phrase, infinitive clause is not paralleled with subject or predicate you mentioned above.

Comment: I mean "for passengers to board Flight 139" as a complement, or as a adverbial, or as a attributive, or as an appositive?

Comment: so you think infinitive clause here (to board Flight 139) should be subject or object?

Comment: thanks for your answer,  but I really doubt it. in "This is the last call for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57" , "This" is subject; "is the last call" is linking verb + predicative; and "for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57" I think it's functioned here as attribute modifying noun "call".

Comment: a call(n.) to do sth; call sb to do sth;  call to do sth; call for sth; call for sb to do sth; @Lambie maybe you mix the functions call performed in those cases.

Comment: This is |a call [for x] to do something| just like the dictionary says! Also, we say: to mix something **up**, not to mix something. That would be a cake or other mixture.

Comment: predicative : (of an adjective or noun) forming or contained in the predicate, as old in the dog is old (but not in the old dog) and house in there is a large house. "is" is a linking verb.Except being as noun (a subject or an object), infinitive phrase can also be used as adjective, adverb

Comment: is the last call = the predicate (linking verb+predicative) and [infinitive phrase can also be used as adjective, adverb](https://englishsentences.com/infinitive-phrase/)

Comment: Sorry, can you explain to me simply why "is the last call" is not linking verb + predicative.

Comment: I think it's linking verb + predicative structure as the predicate of the sentence.

Comment: I‘m sorry I really annoying you. I'm not sure you really know exactly what predicative is. noun can be used as a predicative. so in "This is the call", "the call" is predicative, just like Bob is a postman. (nominal predicative of the subject) If I am wrong, maybe you could simply point out the pinch point clearly.

Comment: predicative (plural predicatives)

(grammar) An element of the predicate of a sentence which supplements the subject or object by means of the verb. Predicatives may be nominal or adjectival.
Examples
He seems nice. (adjectival predicative of the subject)
Bob is a postman. (nominal predicative of the subject)
We painted the door white. (adjectival predicative of the object)
They elected him president. (nominal predicative of the object)

Comment: Why don't you simply explain to me the differences between "This is the call" and "Bob is a postman", When I parsing two sentences Wikipedia tell me "Bob is a postman" is "linking verb+predicative" but you say "This is the call" is not, that's where I'm confused about.

Comment: @momstaI wish I had never answered this question.

Answer (score -1):

To make it more cognizable let us take up the pattern where we have the preposional complementation by the infinitive clause: "The stewardess called for the passengers to board the plane". Here we are dealing with monotransitive complementation by the nonfinite clause. In this case the construction is that of a preposional verb "call for" and the infinitive clause  acting as prepositional object.

To verify this:

1. You can replace the infinitive clause by a pronoun or noun phrase: The stewardess called for it; The stewardess called for the boarding of the plane.
2. It can be an answer to a what-question: What did the stewardess call for? ... for the passengers to board the plane. (In cases of the complex transitive complementation - "The stewardess called the passengers to board the plane", you can't say: What did she call?, you can ask: Whom did she call to board the plane? - she called the passengers).
3. It can easily be the focus of a pseudo-cleft sentence: What the stewardess called for was for the passengers to board the plane.
4. Being an object, the infinitive clause can become a subject in the passive: "For the passangers to board the plane is called for".
5. When the object of the infinitive clause, which is "the plane", is turned into the passive form, there is no change of meaning: "The stewardess called for the plane to be boarded by the passengers". (You can't transform "The stewardess called the passengers to board the plane" into "The stewardess called the plane to be boarded by the passengers").
6. In a reduced construction the infinitive marker "to" remains: "The stewardess called for the passengers to". It does not have the same meaning as: "The stewardess called for the passengers" (which means that she demanded that the passengers should come up to her).

As regards your original sentense there is an important difference to be discerned. For example: "This is the last call for the stewardess to give forth", where the nonfinite clause is an attribute (postmodifier) and the predicative (the last call for the stewardess to give forth) acts as a subject complement. But in your pattern the nonfinite clause is rather a relative clause of purpose functioning as an adverbial modifier of purpose. You can ask: "What is the last call intended for" - "It is intended for the passengers to board the flight".

Comment: thanks for your answer. I remember that Merriam Webster's Advanced Learner's Dictionary once said difference existed between "vt. for somebody to do something" and "vt. somebody to do something" is the difference of US English vs British English. (I can't recall the example though even the word for Vt. (transitive verb)). What's in your mind about it.

Comment: call for something (to indicate that something is needed) could be used to explain sentence above. how about cause is regarded as causative verb in "The stewardess called the passengers to board the plane" (call [+obj] - 3a to order someone to come). Dose that make sense? and then the passengers is the object and the to board the plane is the complement. and "for" here which may be omitted is only traced from US vs British English differences.

Comment: This question may appear to be more sophisticated than it seems. "call for" is an intransitive prepositional verb (also called an intransitive phrasal verb with the preposition) which takes a prepositional object, whereas "call" is a transitive verb taking a direct object. These two verbs differ in meaning. When you say:"The stewardess called (summoned) the passengers to board the plane", we have the complex transitive complementation where "the passengers" is the direct object of the superordinate clause and the infinitive clause is the object complement.

Comment: At the same time "the passengers" behaves like a subject in relation to the infinitive verb and therefore is sometimes named the raised object. In a passive construction "the passengers" can become the subject:"The passengers are called to board the plane". But as far as "call for" is concerned, its prepositional object can become a subject in the passive:"(For) the passangers to board the plane is called for" (note that with "call" only "the passengers" is transformed into the subject, while  with "call for" the whole prepositional object becomes the subject in the passive).

Comment: To comprehend the aforecited better: in the pattern with "call for" the stewardess called for boarding the plane, whereas using "call" the stewardess called (summoned) the passengers (to board the plane or to drink coffee with her or something).

Comment: Touching your question about "for": if you say: "The stewardess preferred the passengers to board the plane", "the passengers to board the plane" is a direct object (in contrast to the "call" where only "the passengers" is a direct object), because here we also have the case of monotransitive complementation. In AmE "prefer for" can easily take the place of "prefer" with no change of meaning: "The stewardess preferred for the passengers to board the plane". The "for' just introduces the infinitive clause and marks the subject of this clause.

Comment: "It is not going to be enough for monetary policy to be the only game in town," she said, calling on countries to consider government spending hikes to increase long-term growth. in this sentence, is "for monetary" a purpose adverbial (for ~)? or is it a raised subject as you said above.

Comment: I would say that the whole nonfinite clause is a postponed clausal subject.

Comment: @momsta *for* is a preposition, less often a conjunction. || "The stewardess preferred the passengers to board the plane", is not grammatical in English.

Comment: @Lambie Oxford Advanced English Dictionary says "Their father prefers them to be home early"

Answer (score -1):

I have checked some material which says "for somebody to do something" is a compound structure used to be attribute such as "It’s time for everybody to go to bed." So in this example (This is the last call for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57.) this is the subject; is the predicate; the last call is the predicative or complement for subject; and for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57 is the attributive. is that right? and I wonder if "for passengers to board Flight 139 at Gate 57" could be divided intensively?